# Why am I getting and error from wp_get_attachment_image_src?

Tags: images

```
This Code:
<div id="canvas" class="plan-page" 
         style="background-image: url('<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( stripslashes($options['sitePlan']), 'full')[0]; ?>');"></div>
```

is causing a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content... any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PHP does not support the function array dereferencing, which you want to do. In simple words - you can't treat function as array.

What you should do is:

```
<div id="canvas" class="plan-page" style="background-image: url('<?php
    $image_src = echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( stripslashes($options['sitePlan']), 'full');
    if ( is_array($image_src) )
        echo $image_src[0];
?>');"></div>
```

Or to be even more correct:

```
<?php $image_src = echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( stripslashes($options['sitePlan']), 'full'); ?>
<div id="canvas" class="plan-page" <?php if ( is_array($image_src) ): ?>style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image_src[0]; ?>');"<?php endif; ?>></div>
```

PS. See an RFC on the subject http://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing.

Comment: Thank you, however I was informed that stripslashes is not supported in php 5.3. I need to update to 5.4 or 5.5.